# SWFObject v2 - How to remove annoying 'Click To Activate' message in IE7?

Tags: flash, swfobject

I am using SWFObject version 2, and using its dynamic publishing feature. Typical JavaScript  code to embed flash like (based on its featured example from its documentation page):

```
swfobject.embedSWF(..
```

However, in IE7, I always see 'Click to Activate' message. I heard that SWFObject was supposed to cater this issue, however, my experience with it now make me beg to differ. I am happy to be proven wrong.

Any suggestion, how to remove this issue? Example JavaScript code and/or URL of page using SWFObject is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft removed the click to activate 'feature' about a year ago (Microsoft settled the lawsuit with EOLAS, allowing Microsoft to stop requiring a click to activate plugins). If you still encounter the click to activate message, you probably need to get the latest security patche(s) for IE.

SWFObject 1.x addressed the issue, but SWFObject 2.x no longer addresses that issue since Microsoft has released its browser patch.

Comment: Thanks Pipwerks.

Security patch KB938127, KB963027, and KB960715 fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the [steps detailed in the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) and you should be golden.

Answer (score 1):

add CSS

```
object {
    display:block;
}
```